# Visual Studio 2017, Service Fabric project, Sdk Targets: Error when packaging SF project

Tags: azure-service-fabric

The error displayed during build:
error MSB4102: The value "" of the "Project" attribute in element  is invalid. Parameter "path" cannot have zero length.

Reproduction steps are simple:
VS 2017 RC 2.
Create new Service Fabric Application targeting ASP.Net Core using Web API.
Then attempt to package the service fabric project.

I suspect there is a bug in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.ApplicationProject.targets that is part of VS 2017.
The one that sits in this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Service Fabric Tools

In the sdk targets file, there is this statement.

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(LanguageTargets)' == ''">
    <LanguageTargets Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)' == '.csproj'">$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets</LanguageTargets>
    <LanguageTargets Condition="'$(MSBuildProjectExtension)' == '.vbproj'">$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets</LanguageTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- TODO: Generate error if LanguageTargets property isn't set here.  This would happen, for example if an .fsproj referenced the .NET Sdk 
              but not the FSharp one.  See https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/448 -->
  <Import Project="$(LanguageTargets)"/>
```

A little tough to decipher if you aren't used to it. But. In essence it is saying if it's a .csproj load the CSharp targets, if it is a .vbproj load the VB targets, if neither do nothing.
Then the next line tries to import the targets specified.

In the case of a Service Fabric project, that is a .sfproj, which means LanguageTargets is left blank and we get the error shown at the top of this post. The SF targets file should set LanguageTargets I think, before it reaches this line.

I suspect this sdk.targets file is some default template that hasn't been updated to handle VS 2017 service fabric projects yet.

Possible answer, but I don't like the idea of editing the Sdk.targets file installed by VS. Changing this line in Sdk.targets gets past this error, and doesn't cause any other errors in the build:

Answer (score 2):

From: Matt Thalman at [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19fd8e9c-a517-4361-b50d-656d679d9c8b/visual-studio-2017-service-fabric-project-sdk-targets-error-when-packaging-sf-project?forum=AzureServiceFabric]

This issue should be fixed in the latest version of VS 2017 RC. Be sure you're running the latest.

However, even with the newest version, it is possible you can see this issue in cases where VS or some automated logic has downloaded the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.4.0 NuGet package rather than using the package that ships in the box.  The version of the NuGet package that ships in the box with VS 2017 RC has the fix for this issue.  But the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.4.0 NuGet package that exists in NuGet.org does not have the fix.  There's currently an update to the NuGet package (version 1.4.1) containing a fix that exists but is unlisted.  So if you need to make use of that updated package, you'll need to make some manual changes to your Service Fabric Application project:

Update the packages.config file so that it references version 1.4.1 of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild package.
Update your .sfproj file by replacing instances of "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.4.0" with "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.4.1".
Normally, NuGet would make the project file updates for you automatically when you update the NuGet package version but due to an issue that NuGet has with the Service Fabric Application project type, those updates do not happen automatically which is why you need to make these changes manually (and also why the package is defined as unlisted in NuGet.org).